# Can't add event in OS X calendar app

Tags: calendar, osx-el-capitan

All I want to be able to do is make a small note on a day. Calendar app on osx el capitan won't allow me to add events without registering(?) some account. This is beyond stupid and inconvenient.

Comment: an Apple ID… you already need one to buy apps, tunes, movies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Calendar app on OSX won't allow me to add events without registering an account.

It is probably asking for credentials for an i Cloud account.

If you don't want to do this create a local calendar instead:

> 1. Make sure you have at least one local calendar available to create events in.
> 2. Click the calendars button in the bar on top to see which ones are available, and if there's none, create one in Menu > File > New
>      Calendar.
> 3. Open Menu > Calendar > Preferences and on the bottom set your "Default Calendar" to a local one.

Source [Any way to fix this error? I can't add an event to OS X calendar if I delete my iCloud calendar.](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/3w5hpb/any_way_to_fix_this_error_i_cant_add_an_event_to/)

Comment: You first have to create a local calendar before you can set it as default. The only way I saw to do this is to 1) click the plus sign on the main UX of the calendar app. 2) right click in the area of the UX that opens up on the left. 3) choose new calendar and set a name 4) highlight the newly created calendar. 5) Yay! now you can add a quick two-word note on a day. Why is the default behavior not just being able to add a note on a day?

Comment: @fightermagethief That's why step 3 comes **after** step 2 in my answer ;)

Comment: I mainly posted this question so whoever designed this "feature" can see how retarded it is.